# Vue-router: get rid of trailing slash in the url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

**Setup**: vue 2.6.14 & vue-router, my router config:

```
{
  mode:            'history',
  base:            document.location.pathname,
  routes: [
    {
      path:      '/',
      name:      'main',
      component: Main,
      props:     (route) => {
        return {
          id: route.query.id,
        };
      },
      pathToRegexpOptions: {
        strict: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**Problem**: I have urls like this

```
local.host/page/xxx_111.html?id=111
```

The router base is `/page/xxx_111.html` path. At some point I would like to change the url via programmatic navigation to just

```
local.host/page/xxx_111.html
```

in other words, to get rid of query params, but whatever I do, I always get

```
local.host/page/xxx_111.html/
```

with trailing slash :( How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the strict parameter to false?

Comment: @StevenSpungin yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by making router's `path: '/*([\\w\\-]+_?[\\d]+.html)'` which matches any url of type `local.host/<ANYTHING>/xxx_111.html` and calls like `this.$router.push({ query: {} })` to get rid of url param w/o adding trailing slash to the url.